# Showing a stopping time is finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $T = \inf\{ n : S_n = a \text{ or } S_n = -b\}$ be a stopping time, where $S_n = X_1 + \dots +X_n$ and each $X_n$ is a martingale. I am looking at a proof which shows that $T < \infty$ almost surely. They state:

$$P(T = \infty) \leq P(T > n) \leq P(|S_n| \leq \text{max}\{a,b\})$$

Could someone explain these inequalities for me? The first one holds for all $n$ which I can somewhat see, but I have no idea about the second one. Surely $|S_n| \leq \text{max}\{a,b\}$ doesn't make sense, as if $S_n = a$ or $-b$ then $ T\not > n$?

Comment: But if $S_n=a$ or $S_n=-b$, then $T\not>n$

Comment: @JimmyR. Yes...but you want the implication to go the other way, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: everything else is copied up correctly

Comment: Do you mean that $S_n$ is a martingale? Otherwise it doesn't make much sense to say that each $X_n$ is a martingale, unless I don't know something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have $T=\infty$ you must have $T>n$ for all $n$, so in particular you must have $T>n$ for a fixed $n$. To have $T>n$ for a fixed $n$, $S_k$ can't be $a$ or $-b$ for any $k \leq n$. But this would have to happen at some point if $|S_k|$ ever became larger than both $a$ and $b$. (The process doesn't let you skip over $a$ or $-b$ on the way to the outside of the interval $(-b,a)$.) So $\max_{k \leq n} |S_n|$ has to be less than $\max \{ a,b \}$.

So $\{ T=\infty \} \subseteq \{ T>n \} \subseteq \{ \max_{k \leq n} |S_n| \leq \max \{ a,b \} \}$. Then use monotonicity of $P$ to get the result.

By the way, in the terminology that I learned, a "Markov time" is what you are referring to and a "stopping time" is an a.s. finite Markov time. I'm not sure how *universal* this terminology is, but I find it a useful distinction.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I don't follow why $|S_n| \leq \text{max}\{a,b\}$. Surely if it equaled either $a$ or $b$ we would not have $T>n$?

Comment: @lampj20la That's true, but we're saying $T>n \Rightarrow |S_n| \leq \max \{ a,b \}$ not the other way around. You could say $<$ if you wanted, but there is no real gain from doing that.

Comment: I see - thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Ian May I ask, how does this show the martingale has almost surely finite stopping time? It seems to show only that the probability of the stopping time being infinite is less than that of the sum being a or b.

Comment: I'm also curious as to how we know that $P(\tau = \infty)=0$ from this inequality. I believe that's what we need to show in order to prove that this stopping time is a.s finite.

Comment: @DorisP The actual question makes no sense, I think I was implicitly assuming that $X_n$ were independent nondegenerate mean zero variates so that $S_n$ itself is a martingale.