# Showing that a stopping time is finite for an unbalanced betting game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $\tau=\inf\{n:S_n=a \text{ or } S_n=-b\}$ be a stopping time and $X_n = Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$ a martingale (with $X_0=0$) that describes an unbalanced betting game between two players.
$Y_i$ are independent random variables with $\Bbb{P}(Y_i=1)=p$  $\text{ and }$  $\Bbb{P}(Y_i=-1)=q=1-p$.

I should prove that the stopping time $\tau$ is finite almost surely.

I have found that the same question has already been asked (link: [Showing a stopping time is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720744/showing-a-stopping-time-is-finite)), but I couldn't figure it out and solve the problem. Could someone kindly give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that a stopping time is finite for a biased random walk.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293522/showing-that-a-stopping-time-is-finite-for-a-biased-random-walk)

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain me why the inequality $\frac{1}{n} S_n \ge \frac{1}{2} (2p-1)$ holds?

Comment: If $p\in(1/2,1)$, it holds for $n$ sufficiently large, almost surely, by LLN

Comment: Thank you again!